# Unable to parse XML

Tags: c#, xml

I tried parsing following XML code to extract data but it always gives NULL pointer exception.
XML text is as follows

```
<MyKnobs>
<HeaderDetails targetTable="INVOICES">
<Field targetField="DOC_NO">Ordernumber</Field>
<Field targetField="ORDER_NO">Ordernumber</Field>
<Field targetField="PO">Ordernumber</Field>
<Field targetField="CUSTCHAR1">Ordernumber</Field>
<Field targetField="">Customer</Field>
<Field targetField="ORDER_DATE">Orderdate</Field>
<Field targetField="PO_DATE">Orderdate</Field>
<Field targetField="CUSTCHAR2">Orderdate</Field>
<Field targetField="PROMOTION_CODE">Couponname</Field>
<Field targetField="">Coupon_discount</Field>
<Field targetField="TAX_AMOUNT">Tax</Field>
<Field targetField="SHIP_AMT">Shipping_cost</Field>
<Field targetField="">Creditcardnumber</Field>
<Field targetField="">Creditcardexpiration</Field>
<Field targetField="">Creditcardtype</Field>
<Field targetField="">Credit_authresp</Field>
<Field targetField="">Credit_amount</Field>
<Field targetField="">Credit_avs</Field>
<Field targetField="">Security</Field>
<Field targetField="">Security_response</Field>
<Field targetField="">Processorid</Field>
<Field targetField="">Credit_approval_num</Field>
<Field targetField="MEMOS">Comments</Field>
<Field targetField="">Giftwrapcharge</Field>
<Field targetField="">Couponpercent</Field>
<Field targetField="">Notes</Field>
<Field targetField="">Returnbox</Field>
<Field targetField="">Userorderid</Field>
<Field targetField="">Returnbox2</Field>
<Field targetField="CUSTCHAR3">Sampleorder</Field>
<Field targetField="">Specialshippinginstructions</Field>
<Field targetField="CUSTMEMO3">Howyoufoundus2</Field>
<Field targetField="CUSTMEMO1">Referer</Field>
<Field targetField="CUSTMEMO2">Entrypoint</Field>
<Field targetField="DELIV_METH">Shipping_method</Field>
<Field targetField="SALES_REP">Everestuser</Field>
<Field targetField="CUSTCHAR4">Hoklevel</Field>
<!-- Not Null Fields as following -->
<!--WebSite retrieve from Dropdown-->
<Field targetField="STATUS" DefaultValue="8"></Field>
<Field targetField="SYNC_STATUS" DefaultValue="0"></Field>
</HeaderDetails>
<OrderDetails targetTable="X_INVOIC">
<Field targetField="ORDER_NO">ordernumber</Field>
<Field targetField="ITEM_CODE">Item</Field>
<Field targetField="ITEM_QTY">quantity</Field>
<Field targetField="ITEM_PRICE">UnitPrice</Field>
<Field targetField="">TotalPrice</Field>
<Field targetField="">Name</Field>
<Field targetField="">AccWareSKU</Field>
<Field targetField="">canceled</Field>
<Field targetField="">YahooId</Field>
<!-- Not Null Fields as following -->
<Field targetField="STATUS" DefaultValue="8"></Field>
<Field targetField="SEQUENCE" DefaultValue="1"></Field>
<!--SEQUENCE Increased by 1 -->
<Field targetField="RFC_WARRANTY_PERIOD_TYPE" DefaultValue="0"></Field>
<Field targetField="RFR_WARRANTY_PERIOD_TYPE" DefaultValue="0"></Field>
<Field targetField="RFT_WARRANTY_PERIOD_TYPE" DefaultValue="0"></Field>
</OrderDetails>
</MyKnobs>
```

I want to extract targetTable Value in HeaderDetails and targetField Text and Values of Inner Field.

I tried following code but it is not working.

```
string WebsiteCodeXmlPath = (@"../../Configuration/FieldMapping.xml");
        var xdoc = XDocument.Load(WebsiteCodeXmlPath);
        var Response = xdoc.Descendants("HeaderDetails").Select(c => (string)c).toString();
```

Please help.

Comment: on wich line has the error occurs ? What is the Exception ? Do you debug with a breakpoint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xdoc.Descendants("HeaderDetails")
```

This gets **all descendants with the tag name `<HeaderDetails>`**. You want all `<Field>` tags per `<HeaderDetails>`, if I understand you correctly.

```
var all_headerdetail_tags = xDoc.Descendants("HeaderDetails");

foreach(var headerdetail in all_headerdetail_tags)
{
    var all_fields = headerdetail.Descendants("Field");

    //Now you have all fields of a HeaderDetail object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's  *all* the xml because XDocument.Load requires the xml file to have a proper xml header tag. Do you have a minimal but complete example of xml you would expect to be able to parse?  Have you tried copying the xml text into an inline string and using XDocument.Parse to rule out any possibility that you are not reading the file you think you are?  Have you tried looking at the contents of xdoc in the debugger?